# Laplacian operator in PDE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, laplacian

Consider the following partial differential equation:

$\frac{\partial y(x,t)}{\partial t} = \theta \nabla^2y(x,t)$

where $x \in R^2$ is the spatial index and $t \in Z^+$ is the temporal index. Can you please confirm if the Laplacian operation is obtained from the Hessian matrix which is $3 \times 3$ (spatial and temporal factors) or $2 \times 2$ (only spatial factors) ?

I do not know much about PDEs and my apologizes if this question is too elementary.

Comment: Conventionally the Laplacian is only the spacial variables.

Comment: unless otherwise noted, Chappers is right. Sometimes we'll denote $\Delta_t$ to say if we're talking about a laplacian w.r.t time or another variable.